# Voice changer for Ububtu 20.4 pipewire

Tags: sound

I want to set up an podcast-enviroment with numerous fictive "persons", each with their own voice. For this I need a voice changer where i can save settings for each person, and change person on the fly.
Im using Ubuntu 20.4 with pipewire, so Lyrebird, Clownfish, etc are not compatible.
Can anyone suggest a vioce changer that satisfy the needs mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

The [feature request to add PipeWire support to LyreBird](https://github.com/lyrebird-voice-changer/lyrebird/issues/62) has a long thread with a suggested work-around until format support is available.

In short, from [this comment](https://github.com/lyrebird-voice-changer/lyrebird/issues/62#issuecomment-824728486)

> Just symlinking pactl to pacmd and manually connecting Lyrebird stuff using Catia makes it work on Pipewire.

More detail:

- `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/pactl /usr/bin/pacmd`  to symlink
- [Catia](https://libreav.org/software/catia) for the JACK Patchbay